# Apply function generating random numbers to a matrix (R)

Tags: r, matrix, function

I have a function which basically creates a random number. Now I want to apply the function to a matrix for given conditions to replace the value in the matrix with the random number created by the function. The problem is, that the function creates only a single random number and replaces each value meeting the given conditions with the same number. But I need to replace each value with a different random number. It might become more clear with an simple example:

`#create matrix
my.matrix <- matrix(c(-99,-99,0.1, -99,-99, -99, 0.2,-99,-99), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)`

`#create dataset
x <- c(1:100)`

`#create function
my.function <- function(x){
               rnorm(1,mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))
               }`

`#apply function to matrix meeting given conditions
new.matrix  <-  ifelse (my.matrix > 0, my.function (x), -99)`

`V1        V2  V3
[1,] -99.00000 -99.00000 -99
[2,] -99.00000 -10.42696 -99
[3,] -10.42696 -99.00000 -99`

Since my actual function is much more complex and I need to apply the function meeting several different conditions, I need to use a function and most probably `ifelse`.

Comment: PS this is a coding question so it belongs to SO.

Comment: Not nescessarily - you can solve this by adding matrices together or probabyl some other tricks as well.

Comment: Why fixation on ifelse? You can do any form of subsetting without ever using ifelse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does exactly what you have required of it. Function `my.function` returns *only one* value, and you asked yo put it in everywhere based on condition. I suggest to convert matrix to a vector, do the substitution and return back to matrix. For example:

```
v<- as.vector(my.matrix)
v[v>0] <- fun(v[v>0])
new.matrix <- matrix(v,ncol=ncol(my.matrix))
```

where `fun` is the function which changes stuff. Note that you explicitly pass all the elements you want to change, which gives you lots of control. If I guessed correctly what you want to achieve `fun` might be:

```
fun <- function(v,x) rnorm(length(v), mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))
```

In this case you need to pass x too:

```
v[v > 0] <- fun(v[v > 0], x)
```

Note that you can do this with matrices too:

```
new.matrix <- my.matrix
new.matrix[new.matrix > 0] <- fun(new.matrix[new.matrix > 0], x)
```

Since R simply coerces the values in a subsetted matrix to a vector. But this is a more nuanced approach, you know to need the caveats. Luckily they are all described in Introduction to R, which you can find on http://www.r-project.org.

Answer (score 1):

First, `fun` (or `my.function` as you give two different names to it) returns a single value so how would you expect it to output multiple values?

Second, [`ifelse` returns a value of the same shape as test condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449184/if-else-vs-ifelse-with-lists), e.g.
`ifelse(c(1:2) < 3, T, F)` returns `TRUE TRUE`. The default R behavior is to repeat a single value if replacing multiple items:

```
a <- matrix(NA, 3, 3)
a[1:3, 1:3] <- 5
```

will give you a matrix of 5's.

So what your code does is it replaces multiple items with a single (repeated) output of `fun`.

What can be done is replacing with a vector of outputs of `fun`, for example like this:

```
replace <- my.matrix < 0
my.matrix[replace] <- replicate(sum(replace), fun(x))
my.matrix[!replace] <- -99
```

for loops or other methods could be used in similar fashion.